# Let $v\in V-0$, then $\varphi _{v}: k[x]\rightarrow V : f \mapsto f.v$ is a surjective $A$-module homomorphism.

Tags: representation-theory

**Proposition.** *Let $A=k[x]$ and let $(V,\rho )$ be a finite dimensional irreducible $A$-module. Let $v\in V-0$, then $\varphi _{v}: k[x]\rightarrow V : f \mapsto f.v$ is a surjective $A$-module homomorphism.*

I'm trying to proof some remarks in my book that are not trivial to me. I hope people can spot errors in my reasoning, or show me other ways to look a this. Here is my try:

**Proof.** Let $y\in V$. We need to show there exists a $f\in k[x]$ such that $f.v=y$. If $V$ is 1 dimensional, this is trivially true.

If not, we know that $V$ is irreducible, so if we take a $\mathcal{V}=\text{span}\{v\}$ then there exists an $f$ such that $f.v \not\in  \mathcal{V}$. We can extend $\mathcal{V}$ to the ortogonal complement of $\text{span}\{y\}$ and find that there must be an $f\in k[x]$ that maps to something not in the ortogonal complement, and so it maps to $\text{span}\{y\}$.

To show that this is a homomorphism:

$$\varphi (fg)=(fg).v=f(g.v)=f\varphi (v)$$

Comment: Hint: the image of a homomorphism is a submodule.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Done.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the more general fact that if $V$ is a simple $A$-module (I am used to using the term "simple" for modules and "irreducible" for representations), $W$ is any $A$-module and $\varphi: W\to V$ is a non-zero homomorphism, then $\varphi$ is surjective (note that $A$ can be any ring here).

To see this, we simply recall that the image of a homomorphism is a submodule, and since $\varphi$ is assumed to be non-zero, it cannot be the trivial submodule, so by simplicity of $V$, it must be $V$ itself.